# How to find specific string and dynamic string

Tags: asp.net

How can I get the values in single quote from DescriptionMsg column which having the common string as 'Account Number is changed from'.

```
SELECT Logid, mrd_id, mrd_accountnumber, DescriptionMsg
FROM RecordData_Log
WHERE Log_date > '2020-12-31 23:59:59.999'
AND Log_type = 'Record Updated'
AND DescriptionMsg LIKE '%Account Number is changed from%';
```

Here is the sample output when I run the above sql query.

> " Account Number is changed from '**2**' to '**2121212121**'.Logo is
> changed. "

I need the values in single comma which is 2 and 2121212121 in this example. For multiple records how can I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear if you looking to process get this information in code, or from the query?

I mean, you can always parse out the value.

Say like this:

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT Logid, mrd_id, mrd_accountnumber, DescriptionMsg FROM RecordData_Log " &
            "WHERE Log_date > '2020-12-31 23:59:59.999' AND Log_type = 'Record Updated' " &
            "And DescriptionMsg LIKE '%Account Number is changed from%';"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData = New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows

                Dim str As String = OneRow("DescriptionMsg").ToString.Replace("'", "")
                str = str.Split("from ")(1)

                Dim strFromNumber As String = str.Split(" ")(1)

                Dim strToNumber As String = str.Split(" ")(3)
                strToNumber = strToNumber.Split(".")(0)

                Debug.Print("From num = " & strFromNumber)
                Debug.Print("To num = " & strToNumber)

            Next
        End Using
    End Using
```

With your sample string, the output is:

```
From num = 2
To num = 2121212121
```

Comment: Hi Albert, Thank you for quick response.  But the account number change information is not fixed at start of message. It may be middle of or at the end of string. Here is the example, "Street is changed from 'oak rd' to 'oak rd 1'.<br>Zip is changed from '437705' to '437704'.<br>Contact is changed from 'YOUR NAME' to 'NAME Admin'.<br>Account Number is changed from '20-136033' to '20-136033123'.<br> for Name '#11 Admin systems(1111)' of Distributor  by Admin " Above code not work in this case.

Comment: Thanks Albert for the help. I changed some of your code and it's working.

Comment: Well, different problem, then different requirements. I mean, depending on how complex the string parse gets, then you might consider using regex. But as along as "from" or "changed from" appears in the text, I think you will be fine. The posted example does NOT care how long the string is, or where it appears - just as long as it does. And I suspect that the parse code I posted could become a bit more fancy pants, but it looks to get the basic job done.